# Getting rid of unused css directives

Tags: themes, css, child-theme

I bought a theme (developed on top of another theme as I discovered later), modified it deeply as a child theme and now I have thousands (more or less 15000) of css lines unused.
Is there an efficient way of deleting what I don't need.
By efficient I mean not one by one.
Do you I earn something in terms on performance?

Comment: have you found this answer helpful or you have other thoughts ?

Comment: I still hadn't time to check, however it is a good advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys behind this project I trust a lot.

https://unused-css.com/

Also I used this long time ago:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

However, you need to be careful, because you must not remove some CSS that will be used in the future, or in case some feature is enabled later.