# Can I search posts and pages for css classes?

Tags: posts, css, migration

> Background: I'm migrating a fairly large site to a new theme from an
>   old theme and an ancient, messy implementation.  I want to remove
>   unnecessary css classes that I no longer use from the content.

Is there a way I can easily search posts and pages for css classes I am trying to phase out either via phpmyadmin or wordpress plugin?

**EDIT**: My site is currently on the old theme due to challenges with content being added frequently and I'm developing on both themes in parallel.  Because of this, the CSS classes I wish to find are currently being used and will have active rules applied to them and cannot be found via inactive css utils.  The goal is to find and re-implement the old classes with the new approach.

Comment: I already answered this question once. Sec.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242101/getting-rid-of-unused-css-directives/242111#242111

Comment: Ah, that is a very similar question with one important difference which I will clarify in my question, thank you though!

Comment: If it helps, then good, else I will not do anything. Someone may answer this better.